# SQL add columns based on number of results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add the dates from string_agg in new columns

```
SELECT g.ganado_id,
       string_agg(i.date, ', ') AS date
FROM   inseminacion i 
       INNER JOIN ganado g
           ON g.ganado_id = i.ganado_id
GROUP BY g.ganado_id
```

Actual output

```
|ganado_id|date                               |
|1        |2016-10-15                         |
|2        |2016-10-15, 2017-02-15             |
|3        |2016-10-15, 2017-03-09, 2017-05-27 |
|4        |2017-06-02                         |
```

Desired output

```
|ganado_id|date1      |date2      |date3      |
|1        |2016-10-15 |           |           |
|2        |2016-10-15 |2017-02-15 |           |
|3        |2016-10-15 |2017-03-09 |2017-05-27 |
|4        |2017-06-02 |           |           |
```

My first impression was to use pivot table but I can't figure out how

Comment: Please post the data in your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not running `string_agg()` but run conditional aggregation using a row number:

```
WITH cte AS 
  (SELECT g.ganado_id, i.date, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY g.ganado_id ORDER BY i.date) AS grp_num
   FROM inseminacion i 
   INNER JOIN ganado g ON g.ganado_id = i.ganado_id)

SELECT c.ganado_id
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.grp_num = 1 THEN c.date ELSE NULL END) AS date1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.grp_num = 2 THEN c.date ELSE NULL END) AS date2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.grp_num = 3 THEN c.date ELSE NULL END) AS date3  
FROM cte c
GROUP BY c.ganado_id
```

Comment: Is there a way to hide column date3 in case all results are null? Also show an additional date4 in case it exists?

Comment: You can extend the `MAX(...)` lines as many as you need. As for hiding/showing columns, SQL is a declarative, special-purpose language where columns are structural components as seen here being hard-coded. Once a statement is declared, it is immutable. Resultsets cannot change column structure depending on data. Rows can be filtered though conditionally by data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both tables for your query . . . in other words, the `join` is not necessary:

```
SELECT i.ganado_id,
       MAX(i.date) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 1) as date_1,
       MAX(i.date) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 2) as date_2,
       MAX(i.date) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 3) as date_3
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ganado_id ORDER BY i.date ASC) as seqnum
      FROM inseminacion i 
     ) i
GROUP BY i.ganado_id;
```

Comment: I think that if there are records in `inseminacion` that are not in `ganado` then the join would make a difference in the output.  If not (only the OP knows this), then I would agree with you

Comment: @Hambone . . . Technically true.  But it is a reasonable assumption that field called `ganado_id` would match between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you already have an answer, but for the benefit of others who may have a similar issue, I'd offer as an alternative the use of PostgreSQL's excellent arrays, one of the features that makes it hard for me to go back to using any other DBMS.

```
SELECT g.ganado_id,
       array_agg(i.date) AS dates
FROM   inseminacion i 
       INNER JOIN ganado g
           ON g.ganado_id = i.ganado_id
GROUP BY g.ganado_id
```

On its own, this might actually meet your need outright.  It has the additional advantage of being very scalable, so if your array ever extends beyond three elements, you don't need to change a thing.

Also, if you needed to convert it to the format you listed, it would be a relatively simple task:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT g.ganado_id,
           array_agg(i.date) AS dates
    FROM   inseminacion i 
           INNER JOIN ganado g
               ON g.ganado_id = i.ganado_id
    GROUP BY g.ganado_id
)
select
  ganado_id, dates[1], dates[2], dates[3]
from cte
```

And, of course if the day comes when you have a fourth and fifth date, it would be as easy as:

```
select
  ganado_id, dates[1], dates[2], dates[3], dates[4], dates[5]
from cte
```